# Legendre-Fenchel transformation for $\varphi\, \Big(\,x\, ,\, f\,\big(\,\Phi\,(\,x\,)\,\big)\,\Big)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

The convex conjugate also known as Legendre–Fenchel transformation of a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ is definite by 
$$
f^{\ast}(x^\ast)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\{\langle x,x^\ast\rangle -f(x)\}
$$

> **Question.** For what functions, $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ and $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$  known *a priori* there are functions  $\psi: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ and $\Psi:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>   $$ 
> \Big\lgroup
> \varphi\, \Big(\, x \, ,
>             \,f\circ \Phi\,(\,x\,)\,
>         \Big)
> \Big\rgroup^{\ast}
> =
> \psi \Big(
>             x^\ast,\,f^{\ast}\circ\Psi\,(\,x^\ast)\,
>      \Big)
> ?
> $$

In my efforts, I found in wikipedia a [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Table_of_selected_convex_conjugates) below with some transformations that answer my question for some very particular cases. 
To be more precise in what I am looking for a theorem which schematically says more or less the following.

> **Theorem.** Let a convex function  $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ ( not identically equal to infinity). Let functions $\varphi: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}\to \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\} $ and $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$. Supose that
>
> > **Assumption 1**: $\varphi$  satisfies the following suitable conditions...
> >
> > **Assumption 2**: $\Phi$  satisfies the following suitable conditions...
>
> Then there are functions  $\psi: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ and $\Psi:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>   $$ 
> \Big\lgroup
> \varphi\, \Big(\, x \, ,
>             \,f\circ \Phi\,(\,x\,)\,
>         \Big)
> \Big\rgroup^{\ast}
> =
> \psi \Big(
>             x^\ast,\,f^{\ast}\circ\Psi\,(\,x^\ast)\,
>      \Big)$$

In case $n = 1$ the first four lines of the table give a positive answer to my question under the condition that $\Phi$ and $\varphi$ are afim functions, that is,
$$
\varphi (x,y) = \alpha +\beta \cdot x+  \gamma \cdot y 
\qquad
\Phi (x)= \lambda \cdot x + \delta \qquad \gamma >0 
$$
then there are functions $\psi$ and $\Psi$ as above such that
$$
\psi(x^\ast,y^\ast )= -\alpha -\delta\cdot\frac{x^\ast-\beta}{\lambda}\ 
+\lambda \cdot y^\ast 
\qquad
\Psi(x^\ast)=\frac{x^\ast -\beta}{\lambda\cdot \gamma}
$$
[image]